# Drag & Drop (a file) to Desktop Icons ceased to open it, Replaced with "Move to Desktop"

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop, desktop-icons

I used to be able to drag and drop files *to* some of my **desktop icons** (e.g. Notepad++, AstroGrep, etc.) to **open** them with the applications represented by those icons.

About a month ago (can't recall exactly when this happened), the system **stopped** supporting this feature and now it won't do it anymore. Instead, it would only *"Move to Desktop"* the dragged-and-dropped file.

Any idea how to restore this (very convenient) functionality?

**Notes:**

1. It's not that drag & drop stopped completely. It's only the **open** feature (within drag & drop) that stopped working for some reason.
2. This feature works fine on all my other Windows 7 computers.
3. Deleting and re-creating the Desktop Icons/Shortcuts doesn't help.
4. I found quite a few postings on "[drag & drop not working on Windows 7 64-bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=Drag%20&%20Drop%20%28a%20file%29%20to%20Desktop%20Icons%20ceased%20to%20open%20it,%20Replaced%20with%20%E2%80%9CMove%20to%20Desktop%E2%80%9D&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=o9q&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows%207%2064%20bit%20drag%20and%20drop%20not%20working&oq=windows%207%2064%20bit%20drag%20and%20drop&gs_l=serp.1.1.0i22i30l3.9373.32123.2.34707.40.29.4.7.7.0.154.2442.23j6.29.0.les;..1.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.ICNVTUY_RDo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmg&fp=e73699d4fc82a92d&biw=992&bih=804)" but they don't really apply in my case because other than having lost the ability to **open** a file using drag & drop, copying & moving files using drag & drop still works.

---

**Additional information:**

I used CCleaner to **analyze** (only! not "fix"...) possible registry problems and the the only area that may seem relevant is the following "Missing Shared DLL" in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls`:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\vsavb7rt.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\system.enterpriseservices.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\mscorrc.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\mscordbi.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\mscorsec.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\system.configuration.install.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\microsoft.vsa.vb.codedomprocessor.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\wminet_utils.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\microsoft.jscript.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\diasymreader.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\iehost.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\system.data.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Health Check\Tools\UninstallHPSA.exe
```

Do you spot anything above that may explain this problem?

---

**Update 1:**

Neither `sfc /scannow` nor `regsvr32 "C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll"` (suggested below) work. System restore is not an option right now.

---

**Update 2:**

I tried the following possible fixes suggested by the link @harrymc provided:

[1.](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-management-support/32562-drag-drop-not-working-windows-7-explorer.html#post160089)  Click on any file with the left mouse button and keep the button held down. Now press the Escape key. Didn't help.

[2.](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-management-support/32562-drag-drop-not-working-windows-7-explorer.html#post166413) Disable the "Drag-drop" in Context menu options, apply it then enabled it again. Didn't help.

---

**Clarification:** Dragging & dropping to applications *while they are open* still works. The only thing that stopped working is opening a document/file through a desktop icon.

Also, if I try to drag & drop using the *right* mouse button, the "Open" context-menu item is not listed:

[image]

Additional ideas?

Comment: what happens if you start dragging a file, while doing that press windowskey+D then drop the file on a desktop icon? do you get the "+" icon while dragging a file over an icon?

Comment: @weberik I get the same exact behavior. No, I don't get the "+" icon (since the file I am dragging is on the `C:` drive anyway). This is weird. It used to work.

Comment: Questions: (1) Does the problem exist for all icons ? (try with an icon for notepad). (2) Have you run a registry cleaner sometimes before you noticed the problem?

Comment: @harrymc (1) Yes, the problem exist for all icons (tried it with notepad too). (2) Once in a blue moon I run CCleaner. I ran CCleaner before and it didn't introduce this problem. Why now?

Comment: @AlvinWong I didn't understand your question. Please explain.

Comment: @Daniel I mean if you drag a file to a start menu item (which is technically also a shortcut) or a shortcut shown in Windows Explorer, will the file be opened by that program?

Comment: @AlvinWong Oh, the answer to your question is No. If I drag a file to a start menu item (or a shortcut shown in Windows Explorer), the file will NOT be opened by that program. That is exactly the functionality that I used to have and it stopped working for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: How about you drag with the right (opposite of left) mouse button?

Comment: @AlvinWong If I drag with the right (opposite of left) mouse button, I still can't open. See my update above for the exact screenshot of context-menu items that are available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this may be a problem in the registry. In particular, I think this lies under `HKCR`.

---

I would like you to check some registry data manually first.

**WARNING: Editing the registry can be dangerous. You are warned!**

First, fire up Registry Editor (run `regedit.exe` from the start menu search box).

Then navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe`. On the right you should see `(Default)` of type `REG_SZ` having the data `exefile`. Comment below and **stop here** if this is not on your machine.

Then also navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk`. On the right you should see `(Default)` of type `REG_SZ` having the data `lnkfile`. Comment below and **stop here** if this is not on your machine.

---

If you passed the above check, then you can follow the following steps to attempt to fix the problem.

**WARNING: Editing the registry can be dangerous. You are warned twice!**

The following fixes `.exe` files:

> Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler`. On the
>   right you should see `(Default)` of type `REG_SZ`, but may not be
>   having the data `{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}`.
>
> Now, select "File" -> "Export" on the menu to backup the data.
>
> When you've done exporting the data, you should try editing the data
>   of the item `(Default)`. Double-click on `(Default)`, then paste the
>   following value `{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}` and click
>   "OK" (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

The following fixes `.lnk` (Windows shortcuts) files:

> Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\DropHandler`. On the
>   right you should see `(Default)` of type `REG_SZ`, but may not be
>   having the data `{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`.
>
> Now, select "File" -> "Export" on the menu to backup the data.
>
> When you've done exporting the data, you should try editing the data
>   of the item `(Default)`. Double-click on `(Default)`, then paste the
>   following value `{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` and click
>   "OK" (or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

After that, close Registry Editor and restart `explorer.exe`. The easy way is to log off then log in.

*By default, you can also drop to `.bat`, `.cmd` and some more file types. If you find that you can't also, find a working Windows 7 machine and copy the corresponding registry values.*

Comment: Thanks! I checked the `exefile\shellex\DropHandler` and it is exactly as should be. Then I checked the `lnkfile\shellex\DropHandler` and instead of what you listed above {00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, I have `{83D96563-DB11-42DF-92F9-32CE7BA54ED8}`. Could that be the problem? I will try that the moment I can take a break from the current task I am in. Thanks!

Comment: And... being curious that I am, I couldn't resist [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22{83D96563-DB11-42DF-92F9-32CE7BA54ED8}%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) this [{83D96563-DB11-42DF-92F9-32CE7BA54ED8}](http://www.checkfilename.com/view-details/Altova-DiffDog-Professional/RespageIndex/0/sTab/2/) value and, sure enough, it seems to belong to Altova XMLSpy, which is exactly what I installed on Feb 26, and this is more or less when problem started... I will report back when I can verify the change.

Comment: **Success!** and by the way, I didn't have to restart explorer.exe (or logout) for that to start working. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

most of the "drop targets" are handled by shell32.dll.
you could try to re-register that file by issuing the command:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll"
```

then reboot and check if the problem still exists

just a wild guess, but maybe it helps

Comment: What are the *side effects* of this de-registration of shell32.dll? Does this apply to 64-bit Windows 7 as well?

Comment: well 'de'-registering will probably destroy your system if its even possible. thats why i employ you to 're'-register it, which should have no side effects at all :). it should work for 64 and 32 bit OSs

Comment: Oops... sorry, I meant to write **re**-registration. :) So, if I understand you correctly, I can safely attempt to re-register `shell32.dll` without further side-effects, right? Or better yet: Is there a way to **only check** if `shell32.dll` isn't registered?

Comment: its safe, i tried it yesterday and my computer still works ;). there is no easy way to check if its 100% correctly registered.  btw your "missing shared dlls" have no effect on your windows shell.

Comment: OK. I just tried `regsvr32 "C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll"`, rebooted and... the problem persists. Could that be caused by a Group Policy change by our IT department centrally controlling all our PCs?

Comment: sorry im out of ideas... everything is possible, but a group policy change as the cause is not very probable ;)

Comment: Oh yes, it *is* the problem of drop handlers (see my answer). Your answer in some degree leads me to my answer, so +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and re-create the Desktop Icons/Shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have harmed the registry by cleaning it.
Cleaning the registry is not a good idea if you do not have a very good knowledge of it.

if none of the other answers fix this weird problem,
my suggestion is to use System Restore to rollback Windows to a previous System Restore point dating from before the problem.

For more info see [Using Windows 7 or Vista System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/).

Comment: I didn't use CCleaner to clean the registry. I only used it to get rid of unneeded *files*.

Comment: But something happened which might be impossible to ferret out without System Restore, although the registry destruction might actually have been caused by one of your installed tools. Question: When you drag a file over the notepad icon, does the cursor change from having a "+" to having an arrow?

Comment: Right now I am in the middle of work so I can't reboot the system. As soon I can reboot it, I will try per the suggestions in this thread: (1) sfc (2) regsvr32 . Answering your question: No, the cursor doesn't change from having a "+" to having an arrow.

Comment: Try also the suggestions listed in [this thread](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-management-support/32562-drag-drop-not-working-windows-7-explorer.html#post160053).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried the 2 suggestions mentioned there but still no go (see update). Other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an enormous number of icons on your desktop? Have you installed any desktop organizer tool? (In any case, CCleaner is still a possibility if it cleaned out files from c:\windows.)

Comment: No, I don't have a large number of icons on my desktop. No desktop organizer tool. Weird.

Comment: Yes, weird is the word. I regret to say that I still think that system restore is the only practical solution, unless someone comes up with a better idea.

Comment: I just realized I've been living with this problem for over a month. Restoring to an about a month ago (could be earlier...) isn't very practical for me. Hopefully someone can come up with a possible explanation of why **only the Open** option disappeared. Once we have the explanation, the fix could be easier.

Comment: To downvoter: Why downvote? My analysis of registry corruption was correct, just that system restore was infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "System Restore" , utlity of windows 7 , that is if you already have enabled and configured it to save restore points frequently. Assuming you had it running , just open
system restore first.

In start menu type `System Restore` ,and then click on the utility. A wizard comes up , follow the steps , and select the date at which , you knew for sure , that everything was running fine , and after the restart , hopefully everything is fixed.

---Edit----

The problem seems to be maybe due to some corrupted system files.

There is a tool called System File checker , which checks the integrity of the system files , this has the possibility determine the cause of the problem. Here is [microsoft's support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833), with regard to that utility.

Comment: Unfortunately *System Restore* isn't an option for me right now since I have installed way too many tools required for my work since then. This may be the last resort in case of a disaster and/or when I have time to reinstall things, but being unable to drag-n-drop to open is only annoying, not a show stopper.

Comment: @Daniel , can you try running sfc , and see if you can determiner the issue , just see my edit

Comment: Just finished running `sfc /scannow`: *"Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."* Rebooting after that didn't solve the problem. Going to try `regsvr32` now...