# EXE Drag and Drop doesn't create a shortcut anymore

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

Drag and drop a .exe to the desktop no longer creates a shortcut, instead the action is always to Move the file.  Creating a shortcut has always been the default action for a .exe, but recently the behavior changed.  How do I restore the original behavior?

I believe the change occurred after doing a system restore on 10/16 from a checkpoint taken 10/14.

The registry DropHandlers seem to be the standard ones: e.g.
  HKCR/exefile/shellex/DropHandler: Default RegSz  {86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}

System32/shell32.dll was updated 8/26/15, but I'm pretty sure creating shortcuts was OK in September.

Other options for creating shortcuts still work: Alt Drag, Ctrl+Shift Drag, Right click/Send To/ Desktop, Right click Drag...

Drag and Drop to create shortcut works for one file name: chrome.exe, but the preview action is 'Create link in' instead of 'Create shortcut in'.  This is the only program I've installed (shows up in Program Features), since this problem began (around 10/16)

There is a freeware tool 'WinAero Tweaker', that will customize drag and drop behavior.   The preference: D&D: Create Shortcut, does partially restore the original behavior:  D&D of any file then creates a Link shortcut (preview is Link, created is Shortcut), regardless of file type or destination. After a tweaker 'restore defaults' the bad behavior is back, but at least context sensitive.  My guess is there are D&D configuration rules/policy that can be modified, are now broken, and Tweaker knows how to tweak them.

I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit on Dell core i5 laptop, with windows updates on

There was a similar problem reported March 2013 [Drag & Drop (a file) to Desktop Icons ceased to open it, Replaced with "Move to Desktop"](https://superuser.com/questions/564200/drag-drop-a-file-to-desktop-icons-ceased-to-open-it-replaced-with-move-to). The DragHandler fix used there is already in place for me.